# how to enable elasticsearch return aggregations including the name in the response

Tags: elasticsearch

I m performing some aggregations (by_shop and by_category ) over a data set using elasticsearch. The thing is I get the response where it s not specified the name of each agg and thus it s difficult to parse the response.

Query

```
      "aggregations" : {
        "byShop" : {
          "terms" : {
            "field" : "shopName",
            "size" : 0
          }
        },
        "byCategory" : {
          "terms" : {
            "field" : "category",
            "size" : 0
          }
        }
     }
```

Respone

```
"aggs": [
    [
      {
        "name": "bucket",
        "count": 5075,
        "key": "shop1"
      },
      {
        "name": "bucket",
        "count": 1,
        "key": "shop2"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "name": "bucket",
        "count": 11,
        "key": "Jewelry & Watches"
      },
      {
        "name": "bucket",
        "count": 1,
        "key": "Home & Garden/Home Décor"
      }
    ]
```

Ideally, I would like to see the following:

```
"aggregations": {
    "byShop": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "count": 5075,
          "key": "shop1"
        },
        {
          "count": 1,
          "key": "shop2"
        }
     ]
   },
   "byCategory": {
      "buckets": [
        {
         "count": 11,
         "key": "Jewelry & Watches"
        },
        {
         "count": 11,
         "key": "Home & Garden/Home Décor"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

EDIT

```
productResponse.getAggs().add(searchResult.getAggregations().getTermsAggregation("ByCategory").getBuckets());
        productResponse.getAggs().add(searchResult.getAggregations().getTermsAggregation("ByShopname").getBuckets());
```

where searchResult holds the response from Elastcisearch. It seems that getBucket() trims the names of the aggs , right?

Comment: I'm surprised, how do you send your queries (i.e. using which client)?

Comment: I m using JEST for Java.

Comment: Ok, then please show the Java code you use to retrieve your results

Comment: Hi Val, I edited the question and I added the piece of code. I think you showed my the solution. It s actually the getBucket() that returns only the buckets without names :)

Comment: Yes, that's correct! Glad you figured it out!